# Joins and two possible where clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched, but can't seem to find how I do this.  Basically I have two tables, and if this was slightly less complicated a simple join would work.

What I am trying to achieve is that each pupil chooses two subjects, and he scores a certain amount of points for each subject per week.  Then I want to be able to display the pupil's name, his subject 1, then the score, then subject 2 and the score.  With the query below, this obviously works for showing the score in subject 1, but I'm baffled as how to get subject 2.

```
$query = "SELECT pupils.name, pupils.subject1, pupils.subject2, subjects.week1 + week2 + week3 AS subject1points 
            FROM pupils, subjects 
            WHERE pupils.subject1 = subjects.subject";

$result = @mysql_query ($query);

if ($result) {
    echo....
```

Maybe some sort of subquery?  Thanks in advance.  Then of course I'm finishing off the table and displaying the results.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). You will also want to [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: without seeing your data structure we'd only be guessing. Please share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to `subjects` three times, but you will need to alias them to disambiguate the columns:

```
SELECT 
    pupils.name, 
    pupils.subject1, 
    pupils.subject2,
    pupils.subject3,
    s1.week1 + s1.week2 + s1.week3 AS subject1points,
    s2.week1 + s2.week2 + s2.week3 AS subject2points,
    s3.week1 + s3.week2 + s3.week3 AS subject3points
FROM 
    pupils, subjects s1, subjects s2, subjects s3
WHERE 
    pupils.subject1 = s1.subject
    AND
    pupils.subject2 = s2.subject
    AND
    pupils.subject3 = s3.subject
```

In the above query, `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are the aliases. Once defined, you can use them wherever you would normally use the full table name.

Another way, and my personal preference, is to use the `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT 
    p.name, 
    p.subject1, 
    p.subject2,
    p.subject3,
    s1.week1 + s1.week2 + s1.week3 AS subject1points,
    s2.week1 + s2.week2 + s2.week3 AS subject2points,
    s3.week1 + s3.week2 + s3.week3 AS subject3points
FROM 
    pupils p
JOIN
    subjects s1 ON p.subject1 = s1.subject
JOIN
    subjects s2 ON p.subject2 = s2.subject
JOIN
    subjects s3 ON p.subject3 = s3.subject
```

In the above query, I also aliased `pupils` to `p`. I like this syntax more because it's very clear. If any of the pupils' subjects can be null (`subject1`, `subject2`, or `subject3`), then you may want to change these to `LEFT JOIN`s so that you can still see the results from any non-null subjects.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it makes sense, I will put it into practice in the morning to see if it's all working for me.

Comment: You're welcome. And please consider Jay's comments on your question, what's described by him there is very important.

Comment: This all works brilliantly.  How would I add though a ranking column to the results?  I have tried looking at some kind of COUNT function but cannot get any of them working and I'm not sure it's because of the joins.

Comment: Don't worry, I have added a very simple $rank = ($rank+1);

Which is then displayed like this:  <td align="left">'.$rank.'</td>

Does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use three joins.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT p.name, p.subject1, (s1.week1 + s1.week2 + s1.week3) as score1,
       p.subject2, (s2.week1 + s2.week2 + s2.week3) as score2,
       p.subject3, (s3.week1 + s3.week2 + s3.week3) as score3
FROM pupils p LEFT JOIN
     subjects s1
     ON p.subject1 = s1.subject LEFT JOIN
     subjects s2
     ON p.subject2 = s2.subject LEFT JOIN
     subjects s3
     ON p.subject3 = s3.subject;
```

Note you should learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax, particularly if you are relatively new to SQL.  Now is the time to start good habits.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a query joining a pupil table with 2 copies of subject table.

**Edit**
I won't bother coding the idea I expressed because others have done it. However, there are only 2 subjects, not 3 (and 3 weeks for score), but that just means leaving `s3` out.